# Divergence of a displacement vector field multiplied by delta function

Tags: vector-fields, continuum-mechanics, dirac-delta-distributions

I'm trying to work out why
$$ \boldsymbol{\nabla\cdot[u}\,\delta^3(\mathbf{r})]=0,
$$

where $\boldsymbol{u}$ is the displacement field of a source of stress, $\boldsymbol{\nabla\cdot u}\ne 0$, and $\delta^3(\mathbf{r})$ is the 3d delta function. I suspect that it could have something to do with

$$
     \delta^3(\mathbf{r})=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\nabla^2\frac{1}{r},
$$
but I could be wrong. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Has $u$ got a particular value for $r=0$ or is it a completely arbitrary field? Maybe you can use the fact that $f(x)\delta(x)=f(0)\delta(x)$

Comment: i'm not sure what to make of $\boldsymbol{\nabla\cdot}\delta({\mathbf{r}})$ in that case then.

Comment: So in that case then $\boldsymbol{\nabla\cdot  [u}\delta(\mathbf{r})]=\delta(\mathbf{r})\boldsymbol{\nabla\cdot u}|_{r=0}+\boldsymbol{u}|_{r=0}\boldsymbol{\cdot\nabla}\delta(\mathbf{r})$, which would be zero then as $u|_{r=0}$ is constant

Comment: Nevermind, I think my remark was pretty useless, I attempted an answer anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The distribution $D(\vec{r}) = \vec{\nabla} \cdot \left[\vec{u} \delta(\vec{r}) \right]$ is not equal to zero.**  Two distributions are equal if and only if you get the same result when you multiply them by *any* test function $f$ and integrate the result over their domains.  This means that if $D(\vec{r}) = 0$, then the integral $$\int D(\vec{r}) f(\vec{r}) d^3\vec{r}$$
would have to vanish for *any* test function $f(\vec{r})$.  But integrating this expression by parts, we obtain
\begin{align}
\int D(\vec{r}) f(\vec{r}) \, d^3\vec{r} &= \int \vec{\nabla} \cdot \left[\vec{u} \delta(\vec{r})\right]f(\vec{r}) d^3\vec{r} \\
&= \int \vec{\nabla} \cdot \left[\vec{u} \delta(\vec{r}) f(\vec{r}) \right] d^3\vec{r} - \int \delta(\vec{r}) \vec{u} \cdot \vec{\nabla} f(\vec{r}) d^3\vec{r} \\
&= \oint \left[ \vec{u} \delta(\vec{r}) f(\vec{r}) \right] \cdot d\vec{a} - \left[\vec{u} \cdot \vec{\nabla} f \right]_{\vec{r} = 0}.
\end{align}
The first term does vanish, since the delta function is zero everywhere on the boundary.  The second term, however, does not vanish in general.

The second term *does* automatically vanish when $\vec{u}(0) = 0$, though. In that case, we can say that $D(\vec{r}) = 0$.  Perhaps this is an implicit assumption concerning $\vec{u}$ in stress fields?  (It's been a long time since I've looked at continuum mechanics in detail.)

Comment: Thanks. $r=0$ is the position of a dilatation centre and $\mathbf{u}$ is the displacement field of a second source of stress. So, would it make sense for the displacement due to the second stress source to be zero at the dilatation centre?

Comment: @stressed1767:  That sounds plausible to me. But while I'm pretty good with distributions and mathematical physics, continuum mechanics isn't my area of expertise.

Comment: if $\vec u(0)=0$ then $\vec u(\vec r) \delta (\vec r)=0$ identically , so then what is left to prove?

Comment: @hyportnex:  The main point of my answer is that the distribution is *not* zero when $\vec{u}(0) \neq 0$.  That said, I agree with you that $\vec{u}(\vec{r}) \delta(\vec{r}) = 0$ when $\vec{r} \neq 0$.  But since the delta-function is effectively "infinite" at $\vec{r} = 0$, $\vec{u}(\vec{r}) \delta(\vec{r})$ is indeterminate there.